# Battery status not shown on Asus K53E - Ubuntu 12.04 LTS

Tags: 12.04, asus, battery

I have `Asus K53E`. My OS is `Ubuntu 12.04.1 LTS`. When I installed Ubuntu, `battery status` was shown but after a month it stopped working. Now I'm not warned if battery level is low or something happens. Laptop just turns off.

I know how to fix this, but this is not permanent decision. What I do is: I leave my laptop to work on battery until it turns off by itself. Then when I turn on laptop again, battery status is shown how it has to be. But after a day or two status is like before.

Could anyone help me with a permanent fix?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try reinstalling the `indicator-power` package using the following commands:

```
sudo apt-get purge indicator-power
sudo apt-get install indicator-power
```

**If this doesn't help**, check the power settings.

- Open Dash and type *Power* or go to *System Settings* > *Power*.
- Make sure the *Show battery status in the menu bar* is set to either *When battery is present* or *When battery is charging/in use*.

[image]

Comment: I tried this but it didn't help. Thank you. :)